# Recurse through mappings in SQL

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table like this:

```
[Mappings]

Parent | Child
---------------
   4   |   10
   1   |   4
```

In SQL, I'm trying to run a query with an input of `10`, and get back all of its parents up the chain... so `4` and `1` in this case.

If I run this with an input of `4`, it would return `1`.

I'm thinking I need to use a common table expression (CTE), but the syntax is throwing me off.

Comment: What RDBMS?  the language can be specific

Comment: Its ansvered here :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170635/get-all-parents-for-a-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170635/get-all-parents-for-a-child)

Comment: This is SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you use sql server, if yes, then you need something like this:

```
create table #test(
Parent int,
Child int
);

insert into  #test
values
(4   ,   10),
(1   ,   4),
(10   ,   12);

with rec as (
    select #test.*, 1 as lvl from #test where Child = 10
    union all
    select #test.*, lvl + 1 as lvl from #test    
    inner join rec   
    on #test.Child = rec.Parent
)
select parent, lvl from rec
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Also maybe  useful to see level column (`lvl` in this case)