# Get all parents for a child using SQL

Tags: sql, database, recursion, hierarchy

I have a table with attributes (CommunityID, Name, Description, ParentCommunityID) called communities. `CommunityID` is the primary key and `ParentCommunityID` is a foreign key refer to this same table. Communities which doesn't have a parent has NULL in their `ParentCommunityID` value. I want to select all the parents of a Community.

I have tried using a answer found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170635/get-all-parents-for-a-child). but when I enter a community which don't have Parent Community (In my case parentCommunityID IS NULL) It gives wrong answer. Also If I remove `DISTINCT` keyword from `select DISTINCT ParentCommunityID` it gives same `CommunityID` twice sometimes.

```
with communities as 
(
   select CommunityID, ParentCommunityID
   from communities
   where CommunityID = 268 
   union all
   select c.CommunityID, c.ParentCommunityID
   from communities c
   join communities p on c.CommunityID = P.ParentCommunityID 
   AND c.CommunityID<>c.ParentCommunityID 
) 
select ParentCommunityID
from communities
ORDER BY ParentCommunityID;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code? I want to select all the Parents of a Community. I don't have a clear idea about this Query as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "communities" as an alias for with. It should be different so you could have a clear definition of your join:

```
with _communities as 
(
   select CommunityID, ParentCommunityID
   from communities
   where CommunityID = 11
   union all
   select p.CommunityID, p.ParentCommunityID
   from communities p
   join _communities c on p.CommunityID = c.ParentCommunityID 
) 
select ParentCommunityID
from _communities
where ParentCommunityId is not null
ORDER BY ParentCommunityID;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3702d4b6ec9eea098a7433001722622)

Comment: It works fine on your DbFiddle demo. But it gives `Error Code: 1146. Table 'test._communities' doesn't exist` when I execute it on MYSQL workbench. test is my Database name.